# CSV file coulmn/field have html tags which breaks the webpage display

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, csv

So I have csv file which has over 2 million data and a Codeigniter webpage to display the data.

the csv data would look for example like this:

```
"KN10001", "example-company", "<a>admin@example.com</a>"
"KN10002", "example2-company", "<p>admin-2@example.com</p>"
```

I tried importing it into mariadb sql via command line:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/citest/csv/listmaster_20171127023429.csv'
INTO TABLE company
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(id, company, url);
```

It did upload, but when I try to display it on the webpage it is broken (tables are broken, missing button), there are missing div tags.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you intend for that HTML to be parsed and displayed by the browser ? If not, then you'll need to wrap it in htmlspecialchars so that the first line shows up as <a>...</a> and not as a clickable link.

Comment: It would probably help if you included the code which generates the web page.

Comment: Please provide the webpage output.

Comment: Seems to be a massive mistake to put html like <p> or <a> tags in your data. Even if you were scraping this data, you should have cleaned it first.